# Infinite loop when I remove a node

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I am getting an infinite loop when I remove a node.

Here is where the node is being removed:

```
llist *modify_sorted_total(gymnast_info *ginfo, llist *head) {

    llist *accu = head;
    int pos = 0;

    while (accu) {
        if (strcasecmp(ginfo->lastname, accu->g->lastname) == 0 &&
            strcasecmp(ginfo->firstname, accu->g->firstname) == 0) {
            remove_node(accu, pos);
            add_sorted_total(ginfo, head);
            return head;
        }
        pos++;
        accu = accu->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is my remove node function:

```
void remove_node(llist *head, int pos) {
    int i;
    llist* list = head;
    for (i = 0 ; i < pos ; i++)
        list = list->next;

    llist *temp = list;
    if (pos == 0) {
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    } else if (pos > 0 && list->next) {
        temp = list->next->next;
        free(list->next->next);
        free(list->next);
        list->next = temp;
        free(temp);
        return;
    } else if (pos > 0 && !list->next) {
        list = head;
        for (i = 0 ; i < pos - 1 ; i++)
            list = list->next;
        free(list);
        list->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}
```

So this is how I have been running my tests. The list is created, which certainly works.:

```
fprintf(stdout, "\nEyeball tests starting!\n\nTesting create_gymnast:\n\n");
    float test_scores1[NUM_EVENTS] = {8.7, 8.5, 8.4, 8.2};
    float test_scores2[NUM_EVENTS] = {5.2, 5.7, 5.4, 5.6};
    float test_scores3[NUM_EVENTS] = {3.8, 3.7, 3.6, 3.7};
    //float test_scores4[NUM_EVENTS] = {1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4};                                                 

    gymnast_info *adam = create_gymnast("Adam",
                                "Fonseca", USA, test_scores1);

    gymnast_info *jersey = create_gymnast("Jersey",
                                "Fonseca", USA, test_scores2);

    gymnast_info *joshua = create_gymnast("Joshua",
                               "ZZZ", CHINA, test_scores3);

    gymnast_info *zach = create_gymnast("Zachary",
                               "middle", MEXICO, test_scores3);

llist *test3 = (llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist));
    test3->g = joshua;
    test3->next = NULL;

    fprintf(stdout, "Jersey should be added to the end:\n\n");
    print_list(add_sorted_total(jersey, test3), stdout);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nZachary should be added to the middle:\n\n");
    print_list(add_sorted_total(zach, test3), stdout);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nAdam should be added to the end:\n\n");
    print_list(add_sorted_total(adam, test3), stdout);

print_list(modify_sorted_total(joshua, test3), stdout);
```

Joshua is being printed out infinitely. When I try to ctrl-c in gdb, it says it's at "??." Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also, when it comes to linked lists, it often helps using pen and paper to draw a few different lists and attempt to do the list-operations on paper.

Answer (score 1):

one big issue:

```
    temp = list->next->next;
    free(list->next->next);
    free(list->next);
    list->next = temp;
    free(temp);
```

temp points to list->next->next, you already called `free` on it. Double free on the same location is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Even with 1 free it fails because you're assigned a freed location (`temp`) as `list->next`

I believe you want to remove & free one element. That code should suffice:

```
temp = list->next->next;
free(list->next);
list->next = temp;
```

It saves `list->next->next` in `temp` (because after `list->next` is `free`d, it's not legal to traverse it anymore), then it assigns it to the now freed `list->next`: you just shortened your linked list without memory leak and without undefined behaviour.

The last case (removing the last element) is also a problem. You should memorize the before-last element to set `next` to `NULL`

Then when doing this:

```
    free(list);
    list->next = NULL;
```

`list->next` sets the next element to the deleted one to `NULL`: illegal & you're freeing the wrong element. You mean:

```
free(list->next);
list->next = NULL;
```